# How to fix “QiskitChemistryError:PySCF is not installed”

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I’m trying to simulate LiH using VQE. But I keep getting the error
QiskitChemistryError:PySCF is not installed
And I tried several ways to see whether my driver for the molecule was typed wrong. But couldn’t find any. I again downloaded the VQE molecule Jupyter notebook from the qiskit documentation and tried running it without any modification. It still gives me the same error.
(Running with the updated qiskit version 0.20.0 on Windows10)

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would need to install it through `pip install pyscf`, however I believe `pyscf` does not support Windows. If you look on their [installation guide](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/install.html) they give some instructions for installing the library, but on Windows you probably need to either use the [ubuntu subsytem for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) or set up a VM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run PySCF on Windows by first downloading [Visual studio installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=docs.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=button%20cta&utm_content=download%20vs2019%20rc). After installing it, you have to install desktop development with C++ in there and it'll solve your issue most probably.